# convert string to both date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I have a data where date and time comes up in yyyymmdd_time (20161012_1528) format.

I want to convert it to date time in SQL Server DB as 2016-10-12 15:28:00:00

is there any straight forward way to do this.or have to create a custom function?

Answer (score 7):

```
Declare @String varchar(25) = '20161012_1528'

Select cast(left(@String,8)+' '+Stuff(right(@String,4),3,0,':') as datetime)
```

Or

```
Select cast(Stuff(Replace(@String,'_',' '),12,0,':') as datetime)
```

Returns

```
2016-10-12 15:28:00.000
```

Comment: @Sami Very kind.  Always nice to hear from fellow developers

Comment: But I believe when we use Stuff it hinders the performance.. Datetime.ParseExact didn't work for me though .. does anyone have any example how to convert to datetime using datetime.parseexact in C# for my format

Comment: @user1046415 Just because you made me curious, I ran a quick test on 50,000 records..  Selecting (to the screen) WITHOUT the calculation 397ms. WITH the calculation 458ms.   Times where an average of 5 runs each

Comment: @user1046415 Update: I was streaming NetFlix.   Results without NetFlix  344.6 and 354.2  (cost of 10ms with the calculation)

Comment: ok . I will try indexing and see if it improves in my case.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try following method,
It requires a few datetime and convertion functions to be used

```
declare @dt datetime
declare @str varchar(40) = '20161012_1528'

select @dt = 
    DATEADD(MI, CAST(right(@str,2) as int), 
        DATEADD(hh, cast(SUBSTRING(@str,10,2) as int), 
            CONVERT(datetime, left(@str,8))
        )
    )
select @dt
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find was datetime format 112 which does not account for the "_hhmm".  I would highly recommend just placing the convert into your T-SQL as the optimizer does not handle UDFs very well.

The T-SQL looks like:
DECLARE @datetimestring nvarchar(max) = '20161012_1528'

```
SELECT
    dateadd(
        minute,convert(
            int,substring(
                @datetimestring,charindex(
                    '_',@datetimestring
                )+3,2
            )
        ),dateadd(
            hour,convert(
                int,substring(
                    @datetimestring,charindex(
                        '_',@datetimestring
                    )+1,2
                )
            ),convert(
                datetime, substring(
                    @datetimestring,0,charindex(
                        '_',@datetimestring
                    )
                ), 112
            )
        )
    )
```

The other option is to format the string to the expected date format which is shorter.

```
SELECT
    convert(
        datetime,replace(
            stuff(
                stuff(
                    stuff(
                        @datetimestring,5,0,'-'
                    ),8,0,'-'
                ),14,0,':'
            ),'_',' '
        )
    )
```